# can I create a new gesture in Microsoft's Hololens?

Tags: hololens

Can I create a new gesture in Microsoft's Hololens? If so, how? I would like to manipulate their holograms further and use my own hand gestures.

Comment: At this point you have following gesture options: Tap, DoubleTap, Hold and Navigation movements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, at this point it's not possible to "create" additional gestures.